# linux rename multiple files using rename

Tags: regex, linux

I have a bunch of files (several thousand) called:

`output.temp.1.csv`
`output.temp.2.csv`
`output.temp.3.csv`
etc.

I would like them all to be renamed but having the `.temp` removed

`output.1.csv`
`output.2.csv`
`output.3.csv`
etc.

I think `rename` is what i need but not sure how to go about doing it

I tried:

`rename 'output.temp' 'output', output.temp.*.csv`

But this didn't work...

Any advice on how to get this changed?

Thanks...

Comment: read about mmv (multiple move).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
rename 's/output\.temp/output/' output.temp.*.csv
```

This will rename 3 files to:

```
output.1.csv
output.2.csv
output.3.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution for renaming all the files:

```
ls -ltrh | grep -i output | awk '{print $9}' | awk -F\. '{print "mv",$0, $1"."$3"."$4}' | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Going off anubhava's answer, if all your files aren't in the same directory, you can use

`find path/to/dir/ -name 'output.temp.*.csv' -exec rename 's/output\.temp/output/' {} +`

To rename all the files in `path/to/dir` and any of its subdirectories.